# Branch and Merge abilities in a Document Database?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, ravendb, document-database

When I think of a document database, I think of a bunch of JSON files.  (I imagine it is more complex than that, but that is how envision it.)

In an upcoming project, we need the ability to deal with multiple different versions of the data.  As I got to looking at the needs, they are very similar to the needs that drive branching and merging of code.  (Versions of the data moving through a process, emergency updates to the existing data in prod even though there are active versions being worked on, etc)

**This has me wondering, do any of the popular document databases have features that are similar to branching and merging of documents?**  (I tried searching around, but I could not get any relevant results.)

Answer (score 2):

[RavenDB](http://live-test.ravendb.net/studio/index.html) has great **Revisions** and **Patching** features.

With **Revisions**  you can keep track of your documents history
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/server/extensions/revisions
https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/4-deep-dive-into-the-ravendb-client-api#document-revisions

With **Patching** you can update existing data in production
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/client-api/operations/patching/single-document
https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/2-zero-to-ravendb#patching-documents